# Windows-Authentication redirect Page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have a **Windows Authentication** Intranet site.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"  >
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

If the user fails the authorization on the Controller,

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class SearchController : BaseController
```

I want them directed to ~/UnAuthorized/Index

Can this be set in the **Web.Config**, similar to Forms authentication where I can redirect to a login page? I just want the redirect to a simple [AllowAnonymous] Controller I have at  (~/UnAuthorized/Index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be easily set. If a user is not authenticated for a given application the user agent is prompting him to provide his credentials. You don't have much control over the UI aspect of this dialog with Windows Authentication.